# D'alembert's wave equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand D'alembert's solution to the wave equation. I'm stuck on the change of variables: $$\xi = x - ct,  \eta = x + ct$$
which allows $$u(x,t) = u(\xi(x, t), \eta(x, t)).$$
How is it that we're allowed to substitute for x (and t) a linear function of x and t? I'm sure this concept has a name but I'm rusty on the topic, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any substitution is *allowed* (up to invertibility, and even that can be circumvented).  The substitution you cite is nice because it causes the differential operator to become the product of two operators, each a differential operator in one variable only.  This leads to "separation of variables".  However, *knowing* that this change of variables works requires studying the method of characteristics, or already knowing the solution so that the substitution is made *a posteriori* from the author's point of view.